# Algorithm to Solve Constrained Longest Path Problem

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, linear-programming, brute-force, bellman-ford

I am a matrix that represents the shortest path between any two nodes, which I compute from a weighted adjacency matrix using Floyd Warshall algorithm. Additionally, I have a constant maximum weight. My goal is to find the path that maximizes the number of vertices visited, while enforcing that the final total path weight is less than or equal to the weight limit. One option would be to generate all permutations, but this would be exponential time, no?

Another thought was to apply dynamic programming with subproblems defined as the max number of nodes from met from node i to node j subject to the constraint. Finally, I thought to reduce this to a linear programming problem with variables equal to edges. Then, would it be equivalent to the kidney exchange problem? After I check that there are no negative cycles, does this imply that there will be *no* cycles in the final optimal path? Please let me know if I can clarify any part of the problem.

I create the shortest path matrix with the following function:

```
def floyd_warshall(G):
    n = len(G)

    # run a modified Bellman-Ford's algorithm on `G`
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                # if better path is found, relax
                if G[i][j] > G[i][k] + G[k][j]:
                    G[i][j] = G[i][k] + G[k][j]
    return G
```

Comment: It's an NP-hard problem, so we have to inquire about the scale of your intended input and tolerance for approximation.

Comment: I would prefer to not use an exponential time algorithm. I am, however, okay with a pseudo-polynomial runtime. Would the solution be similar to the knapsack problem with a few additional constraints? I need to return the globally optimal solution, not an approximation.

Comment: It's strongly NP-hard, unfortunately, by reduction from Hamilton path, so there's no known pseudo-polynomial time algorithm.